# can't debug wince app

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

Firstly,my environment is VS2005, and I want to debug app in the wince6.0 device.
I use Mfc.
I can deploy fine (I have linked vs2005 with the device successfully) and run the forms application through network.

Problem: Debugging wont start. It locks up VS2005. It seems to deploy the app fine, then hangs. Eventually it has no response, and vs 2005 is dead.
A little help for me is very important. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a thread gets in a tight loop and starves the RNDIS session, you will lose your activesync connection. VS2005 may very well lock up in this case.

Things you could try:

- Does your app run okay when it's not on the debugger?
- Can you debug application on the emulator?
- Can you debug a trivial app on your device? (just a main function and a printf, for example)
- Re-install VS2005 and your SDK
- Upgrade to VS2008

Comment: Thank you very much, PaulH. VS2005 in pc connects with wince device without activesyync. Until now, the problem is not sloved. Then, I veritified your advice as listed.

Comment: I am sorry for uncompleted answer because of interruption of power supply. 
I have verified your advice as listed .  
1 My app runs very well in device, and vs2005 can deploy app to the device successfully through net. 
2 I can debug app on the emulator.
3 I can't debug any app even though the app is very simple.
4 I don't reinstall vs05 and sdk, but I make a try on another computer, which is failed.